# Django Admin - Re-authentication?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm in a bit of a dilemma at the moment regarding Django's admin backend. The default authentication system allows already logged-in users that have staff privileges to access the admin site, however it just lets them straight in.

This doesn't feel “right” to me, and I'm wondering if it would be difficult to *at least* require a re-authentication of that same session in order to get into the backend.

Preferably though, it'd be good if the frontend sessions could be separated from the backend ones (though still using the same user objects), this would allow a clean separation of both parts of the site. Would this perhaps require two separate authentication backends? Would something like this be difficult to achieve?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an idea: run the admin app on a different domain to the frontend. The cookies won't be valid in the other domain, so the user will have to log in again. All you'd need would be a separate Apache vhost and a basic settings.py that just has `contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably implement a middleware that asks for authentication when accessing the admin site from a referer not in the admin site.  It could log the person out and make them log back in, but even that wouldn't be necessary.  Just require another password entry, and redirect them if it fails.  It might involve setting a session variable, `is_admin_authenticated` or something.

Comment: Keep in mind that the referrer can be touchy depending on your audience.  Some "Internet Security" suites filter the referrer header out of requests.